# pip keeps removing 'site--packages' & egg's from 'site-packages' from path

Tags: python, import, importerror

**Edit:** looks like pip is to blame but not sure how to fix it

---

I seem to be having a bit of problem with my Python 2.7 installation. Ever now and then for no obvious reason previously working imports of modules like the one below stop working.

```
> import networkx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named networkx
```

After doing some digging I found the output fro `print sys.path` to be much sparser than expected (sorry don't have the output, will update next time it happens). As far as I remember it has no 'site--packages' & egg's from 'site-packages'.

The only way I have found to fix this is to re-run the installer and "repair" Python. This has become tiresome and I would like to find the root cause of this.

1. **Has anyone experiences this problem before? How did you resolve it**
2. **What can I do to trace the cause of this issue?**

---

**Update 1** This is the output of `sys.path` when this problem happens

```
['', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 
'C:\\Python27\\Lib', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 
'C:\\Python27\\Lib\\lib-tk',
'c:\\Python27', 'd:\\dev\\bin']
```

---

**Update 2** Happened again, this time I took a copy of the python27 folder, ran the fix (aka repair the install) then did a diff over the files to see if there was any differences. There was nothing different. Also checked the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Python\PythonCore\2.7` keys for anything strange. There is a value for `PythonPath` but that does not seem to have any issue with it. Will check next time.

Comment: `echo $PYTHONPATH` would be a start. Likely, some setting in your environment is off.

Comment: if you have multiple versions of python installed - could be a problem. what is the problem with simply running `print sys.path` in the interpreter right now and putting that here?

Comment: I've just 'fixed' the issue again so only have the output of when it's not broken. %PYTHONPATH% (I'm on windows) is empty. Yes do have multiple versions installed however only been using 2.7 recently.

Comment: Did you ever igure this out? This is happening to me as well but on mac. https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7912 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61600061/why-does-pypi-pip-try-to-delete-site-packages-when-uninstalling-a-package